# "As soon as" usage check

Tags: conjunctions

Is this usage properly grammatical?

> People returned home as soon as it being evening.

Answer (score 3):

No. Perhaps you meant "People returned home as soon as it was evening."

This is an example of the use of a generic pronoun (it) to refer to the state of things overall at the time of the comment -- "It was raining." "It was hot." "It was evening." It has no antecedent, but instead is understood to refer to the situation in general.

Just as another comment: it is unnecessary, and not entirely polite, to put "Please answer" in your question. The whole point of the site is to ask questions and provide answers, and putting this specific comment in your question looks like you are pushing people to answer this question in preference to others, or just pushing in general. Just ask your question here, and people will answer if it's a reasonable question and they have something to offer.